# Merging multiple TIFF files in one TIFF file

Tags: .net, tiff

I've been trying to use the mergeTiffStreams method of the TiffUtil class posted at:

http://kseesharp.blogspot.com/2007/12/class-for-tiff-manipulation.html

However, like other people have commented on that thread, the end result is that I receive a Stream that only contains my first TIFF file.  The other TIFFs that I passed in the MemoryStream array are not included.

Has anyone else run into this problem before?  If so, any advice would be most appreciated.

Thanks.

[UPDATE]

Here's the code I have at the moment.  The stream that it returns only contains the first TIFF from the array passed in.

```
    public MemoryStream mergeTiffStreams(MemoryStream[] tiffStreams)
    {
        if (tiffStreams == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("tiffStreams");

        Encoder enc = Encoder.SaveFlag;

        ImageCodecInfo info = null;
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo ice in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
            if (ice.MimeType == "image/tiff")
                info = ice;

        EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters(1);
        ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);
        MemoryStream tiffStream = new MemoryStream();
        Bitmap masterBitmap = new Bitmap(tiffStreams[0]);
        masterBitmap.Save(tiffStream, info, ep);

        ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
        for (int x = 1; x < tiffStreams.Length; x++)
        {
            masterBitmap.SaveAdd(Image.FromStream(tiffStreams[x]), ep);
        }

        ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
        masterBitmap.SaveAdd(ep);

        return tiffStream;
    }
```

Comment: That code isn't formatted so reading through it is painful.  I wrote something that did this recently.  You have to extract each page out of the original tiffs and write them to a new tiff.  If you can, I suggest using the WPF API.  The System.Drawing API is basically a facade layer on top of GDI+.

Comment: Were you ever able to find resolution to this problem?

Comment: Update: http://kseesharp.blogspot.com/2007/12/class-for-tiff-manipulation.html does not exist anymore at this point of time

Comment: @goombaloon Were you ever able to find resolution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be in how you're handling the stream returned. If, for example, you want to save it to IO use:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(myPath, tiffStream.ToArray());
```

rather than creating a new Bitmap object from the stream. That was my problem anyway.

Comment: this will create multi-page tiff file or single page tiff file ?

Comment: @ShahrozShaikh - I forgot. A lot of code between then and now:)